# Can Mockito check for reference/shallow equality when `equals` is overridden?

Tags: mocking, mockito

It looks like Mockito invokes the `equals()` method quite liberally on objects needing to be compared.

For example, say I have a class `Ring`, and `myPrecious` is an instance of it. In addition, the `equals()` method has been overridden to do a meaningful and deep comparison (this is an important assumption).

When I use the following Mockito construct:

```
doReturn(42).when(mySUT).putsOn(myPrecious);
```

the custom, deep-comparison `equals()` will be invoked on `myPrecious` by Mockito.

Say, for some reason, I want Mockito to only do the `doReturn` when the object called is indeed myPrecious, not some replica that `equals` it. (

In other words, I'd like the `doReturn` to happen only if the `putsOn` invokes the object that is `==` to myPrecious).

Is there a way to do that?

This would also apply to other Mockito constructs like `verify(mySUT).doTask(myPrecious)`, which also invokes `equals()` on `myPrecious`.

Comment: Unrelated. consider avoiding doReturn(); it makes things much harder to read. `when(mySUT.putsOn(myPrecious)).thenReturn(42)` is much easier to digest.

Comment: Actually, the reason I used `doReturn` was that `thenReturn` always executes `putsOn`, but `doReturn` does not. So if I write `when(mySUT.putsOn(same(myPrecious))).thenReturn(42)`, `mySUT.putsOn(null)` will always be executed. Yes, it makes it easier to read, but I never figured out why Mockito always executes the method at least once when `thenReturn` is used. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Great answer by the way - just what I was looking for.

Comment: @GhostCat Any thoughts on my first comment above? Thanks, and good luck achieving your target.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. You can drop me another comment on Monday to remind me that I am curious about this and want to do some experiments myself :-)

Comment: And hey, I appreciate the accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When just providing an argument, Mockito will in fact use `equals()`.

If you want to write down a call that works for a *specific* object only, you have to use the [same()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#same(T)) matcher.

```
when(mySUT.putsOn(same(myPrecious))).thenReturn(42)
```

should ensure that 42 is returned when something comes in that is == myPrecious.

Beyond that: consider if using the `any()` matcher would be an alternative.

As it *might* be a design smell that you have to make such specifications for your mocks. Meaning: normally, one test should be testing **one** aspect. Therefore: I would step back here and question the implicit requirement: why do you need such specs - does your code under test really need to receive a number different results; depending on which object comes in?